# How can I customise the InAppSettingsKit (background colour & nav bar colour)?

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, inappsettingskit

I would like to change the colour of the background to the InAppSettingsKit view to be black and I would also like to update the navbar colour to a dark grey. However I can't seem to find any details on how to do this.

I have considered just going into the XIB file and changing it manually but it doesn't seem like the right approach. Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you wanna target older iOS releases than 5.0. (For 5.0 and up you could leverage the new UIAppearance stuff.)

If it's just about changing the navigation bar and the striped tableView background, it's pretty easy: I suggest overriding `+[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]` using a category on `UIColor` to return your black color. The navigation bar is even easier, because IASK should inherit the navigation bar from your navigation controller.

If your needs are more complicated, you might wanna resort changing the XIBs.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. How would I go about overriding the method you mentioned? Is it just a matter of re-implementing it in my .m file?

With regards to the navigation bar, I'm not currently using a navigation controller, so is there another way to change this?

Comment: UIColor: yes, just create a new category on UIColor using the Xcode New File assistant. You don't have to include it anywhere, it just needs to be in the project. Navigation bar: You should always have a navigation bar for IASK. If you display it modally, you'd present a new `UINavigationController` with IASK as the root view controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Out of interest where can I find out which methods need to be overridden if I want to change other colours etc. (e.g. the colour of labels in the table)?

Comment: Not possible this way because UIColor is not called when loading a NIB.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way of changing the colour of the labels/headings of the groups?

Comment: Nope because IASK is using the title strings for the tableView section headers. The only way is to use "Custom Group Header Views" (IASK proprietary), see http://www.inappsettingskit.com/